# Can I recreate the code using eval, will it improve performance?

Tags: python, eval

I have an infinite loop using while true
in this loop end, I always check if this is the first iteration of the loop
if this is the first iteration continue, if this is the second and on sleep(1200)

I wonder what is the best way to avoid checking each iteration the if condition? that condition is true only once and I will run the loop for 10^10000 times.

Is there a performance benefit from using eval as so:

```
crazy = r""" crazy = "sleep(120)" """

while True:
    // do some code
    eval(crazy)
```

This will rewrite crazy var at first loop, later will execute the sleep only.
I know it is unsafe, but one day smart code will be a code that write it self.

Comment: Just answered... but... you're using Sleep(1200) each loop, why are you worried about the time it takes to run a single if statement?

Comment: You do realise your code is going to run for 3.805×10^9995 years, right?

Comment: This is sample code.
The if statement is just a simple example of other task that need to be done once.

Comment: Then your code is a not a Minimum Verifiable and Complete example of what you're trying to describe.   Please provide a sample which has an actual performance problem, and define what you think 'good performance' would be, while you're at it, you could test your proposed alternative and see yourself if it's any faster!.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt `eval` is going to be any more efficient than `if`.

If you want to avoid an 'if' then the following code will work.

```
n=0
while True:
    // do some code
    sleep(n)
    n=1200
```

Or to remove that line entirely

```
doSomeCode()
while True:
    doSomeCode()
    sleep(1200)
```

But to be honest, unless you know you have a specific performance problem, that's not masked by the fact you're looping only once every 20 minute, you're probably optimising prematurely.

Comment: I would upvote your answer if it hasn't the "if you really want to" part.

Comment: This will set n to 1200 each loop, even less efficient then branching.

Comment: @SionCohen I can't think of anything that's more efficient than a 'if' statement, it's probably the most fundamental programming construct...

Comment: ok but if you run the if for an unneccery 9999 runs out of 10000 you are just wasting time.

Comment: I still can't imagine an application where that makes any material difference!  See my alternative approach